# How to call gdal_translate from Python code?

Tags: python, gdal, gdal-translate

Is it possible to use some gdal API to call `gdal_translate` from Python code? I do not mean simply executing the gdal_translate.exe from the file system, but rather call it somehow in code so I do not need to know the exact directory the gdal_translate executable is in?

Comment: Yes, as of gdal-2.1.  [This answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/237411/26159) should be accepted as correct.

Answer (score 49):

Since GDAL 2.1 (more info [here](http://erouault.blogspot.it/2015/10/gdal-and-ogr-utilities-as-library.html)), GDAL and OGR utilities can be used as library functions. For instance:

```
from osgeo import gdal

ds = gdal.Open('input.tif')
ds = gdal.Translate('output.tif', ds, projWin = [-75.3, 5.5, -73.5, 3.7])
ds = None
```

If you are going to use `projWin` parameter make sure input raster has SRID set:

```
gdal_edit.py -a_srs EPSG:4326 input.tif
```

Comment: All the options that `gdal.Translate()` takes are listed here: https://gdal.org/python/osgeo.gdal-module.html#TranslateOptions

Comment: I've tried to use this and don't get any errors but the output file isn't created. Any ideas why?

Comment: also getting no output file and no errors. Output paths and projWin params are correct.

Answer (score 31):

The below still works but is outdated. For recent versions of GDAL, see [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/237411/2856).

See the GDAL [API Tutorial](https://gdal.org/tutorials/raster_api_tut.html).

```
#Import gdal
from osgeo import gdal

#Open existing dataset
src_ds = gdal.Open( src_filename )

#Open output format driver, see gdal_translate --formats for list
format = "GTiff"
driver = gdal.GetDriverByName( format )

#Output to new format
dst_ds = driver.CreateCopy( dst_filename, src_ds, 0 )

#Properly close the datasets to flush to disk
dst_ds = None
src_ds = None
```

If you want more output control, such as resizing, subsetting, etc... use a [VRT](https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/vrt.html) as input, this is how gdal_translate does it internally.

Comment: unfortunately this doesn't include reporjection, does it?

Comment: @butcher -  no. Because the question did not mention reprojection.  Of course you can reproject rasters with the gdal python API. If you want to know how, ask a new question.

Comment: I have done it already here: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/103874/gdal-translate-from-within-pyqgis but thius was marked as a duplicate :-(

Comment: @butcher - that was closed as a duplicate of this question. Your question also asks about gdal_translate. Are you aware that gdal_translate does not reproject? If you want to reproject, use gdalwarp or the gdal python API method - [gdal.ReprojectImage](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10538634/737471)

Answer (score 10):

Yes you can call the GDAL Utilities from within Python.  There are very minor differences in the approach depending on whether the utility is an exe in its own right or also a piece of python code.  Either way though you need to use the [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) module:

```
import subprocess

# constants
gdalTranslate = r'C:\Program Files\GDAL\gdal_translate.exe'
src = r"C:\somefolder\somefile.tif"
dst = r"C:\someotherfolder\myresul.tif"
cmd = "-ot float32 -outsize 25 25"  # just for example!

# see note below
def youCanQuoteMe(item):
    return "\"" + item + "\""

fullCmd = ' '.join([gdalTranslate, cmd, youCanQuoteMe(src), youCanQuoteMe(dst)])
subprocess.popen(fullCmd)
```

You will notice that I add escaped quotation marks around my paths.  This is because, on Windows, I have had trouble with paths, especially ones with spaces or where one of the '\' characters makes another accidental escaped character.  So, I just preserve the proper path in aspec as it were.

If you are using one of the python utilities, just do the same thing except your exe at the start of the subprocess command string is now "C:\python32\python.exe" (or whichever version you have) and your second element is the python utility you want to use.

Obviously you can also iterate over your file system rather than using hard-coded constants, but this is just an example.

**EDIT - Generalizing for QGIS plugins**
QGIS creates/modifies a number of environment variables at start up.  So, you can build generalised path variables to the GDAL libraries/utilities using these (see Settings->Options->System) instead of the hard-coded paths in the example above.

Comment: So I can't do this?   import gdal_translate and then call the .main() ?

Comment: No - that won't work.  gdal_translate is not a Python package, so python won't know anything about it.  You will get an error saying "ImportError No Module named gdal_translate".  Use the subprocess module to call it instead.

Comment: ok one similiar questions with using gdal_retile.py.. I tried to do the following:

import gdal_retile  

gdal_retile.main("-v -r bilinear -levels 4 -ps 2048 2048 -co \"tiled=YES\" -targetDir cablepyramid --optfile files.txt")

but I get the error:

Unrecognised command option: -

Any idea why?

Comment: Offhand I can't see the issue except my guess is that it might not like the '--optfile' switch.  The latter is not documented.

Comment: @MappaGnosis Is there an alternative of gdal_translate within Python gdal library?

Comment: @ArditSuice - of course!  GDAL_Translate is just a convenience function.  To use the Python API to do the same thing, just open your raster and then save it in another format.  The tutorials can help you if you are unfamiliar how to do it.

Comment: the above code just works if you know where the GDAL library is located. How to determine the path of this library programmatically, let's say when writing a plugin for qgis that needs to use the gdal_translate command

Comment: See my edit above

Comment: unfort. the GDAL path is not set there... and how to extract the GDAL path in pyqgis is not clear. The GDAL Path is here Raster->GDAL-Tools Settings

Answer (score 9):

I do this with various gdal commands using os.system which you can use to call functions just as from command line:

```
os.system("gdal_translate -of GTiff " + sourcefile + " " +  destinationfile)
```

It's also described in lecture 7 here: http://www.gis.usu.edu/~chrisg/python/2009/

Comment: GDAL commands are available as python functions in GDAL 2.1 through [RFC 59.1](https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/rfc59.1_utilities_as_a_library). Also `subprocess.call` is safer than `os.system`.

Comment: Someone needs to write up a good example of those Python functions; I wrestled with `gdal.Warp()` for a couple of hours to properly get a `PG:` datasource as `cutlineDSName` to drive the `cutlineSQL`. (I know, right? A couple of _hours_ *actually working something out*? The horror!</kidding>). Got it working eventually, and it seems to be significantly faster than `os.system()` or `subprocess.call()`. It's doing ~2 million cutlines, so I won't know if it's _actually_ faster until some time tonight... but it's working exactly right.

Answer (score 7):

Here is a quick code for anyone wanting to save bands from a composite multi-band TIF to individual files using GDAL Translate in Python.

```
import gdal

in_path = 'C:/GIS/Sample.tif' #input composite raster
out_path = 'C:/GIS/Output/' #output directory for individual bands as files

#Open existing raster ds
src_ds = gdal.Open(in_path)

for i in range(1,src_ds.RasterCount +1): #Save bands as individual files
    out_ds = gdal.Translate(out_path + 'band' + str(i) + '.tiff', src_ds, format='GTiff', bandList=[i])
    out_ds=None
```

This could be useful for further processing (e.g. using Rasterio, like [here](http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/gist/om-henners/c6c8d40389dab75cf535)).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a version if you face issues with implementations suggested by @MappaGnosis
It will print errors if any to help you fix arguments.

```
import subprocess

common_args=['gdal_translate', '-sds', '-co', 'compress=LZW']
def export_hd5_to_Geotiff(input_hdf_file):

  target_dir=input_hdf_file.replace('.hdf','')
  target_file=ntpath.basename(input_hdf_file).replace('.hdf','.tif')  
  target_with_path=os.path.join(target_dir,target_file)

  def youCanQuoteMe(item):
      return "\"" + item + "\""
  current_args=[]
  current_args.extend(common_args)
  current_args.append(input_hdf_file)
  current_args.append(target_with_path)
  print(current_args)
  
  if not os.path.exists(target_dir):
    os.makedirs(target_dir)
  proc = subprocess.Popen(current_args,  stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
  stdout,stderr=proc.communicate()
  print(stdout)
  print(stderr)

hdf_files=[item for item in os.listdir(src_path) if item.endswith('.hdf')]

for hdf_file in hdf_files:
  export_hd5_to_Geotiff(os.path.join(src_path,hdf_file))
  break
```