# Gdal Dataset.ReadAsArray() crashes Python

Tags: gdal, numpy, python-2.6, array

I am using Python 2.6.5 (32bit) with Numpy 1.3 and Gdal 1.9.1 installed on Windows 7 64bit.  I am trying to read an 800 MB Imagine (.img) raster dataset into a Numpy array to do some raster algebra, but as soon as I run the following code, Python.exe crashes.

```
from osgeo import gdal

g = gdal.Open(r'path\to\dataset', gdal.GA_Readonly)
b = g.GetRasterBand(1)
data = b.ReadAsArray()
```

Python.exe crashes on the `b.ReadAsArray()` call.  I did some Google searching and found articles dated from Gdal 1.6 that mentioned this issue with Windows 7 64bit, but they also mentioned that it had been fixed in the latest development versions at that time.

Has anyone else had this issue?  Any workarounds?

**UPDATE:**

I decided to debug the code in PyDev to try to determine where it is failing.  From what I can tell (still not getting any error messages) it is failing on line 22 of gdal_array.py.

```
_mod = imp.load_module('_gdal_array', fp, pathname, description)
```

When I step into the line of code above, it brings me into the **init**.py module of numpy.  When I reach the end of the numpy.**__*init*__**.py module, it steps out back to the above line of code.  Then, when I hit the step into button, which should bring me to the next line within gdal_array.py, the script just terminates with no error messages or anything.

**UPDATE #2:**

I uninstalled GDAL 1.9.1 and installed GDAL 1.6.1 from the Python Cheeseshop and OSGeo's Windows Binaries.  Still had the same issue.

Comment: I to was having this issue.  Are you using the gdal python bindings from Tamas at gis.internals?  If so, move your additions to your PATH to the front.  Some other library was causing some issue for me.

Comment: I believe I did download from his internals.  I will try to adjust my path when I get in the office tomorrow.  Thanks for the advice.

Comment: If that does not work, I recently switched to using these packages - http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/

Comment: I tried moving things around in my System Path (PATH environment variable in Windows) with no luck.  I also uninstalled my version of GDAL and installed the version of GDAL on the link you provided and still had the same issue.

Comment: Hmmm....the version that I linked to was only the bindings, so you still need to have GDAL core from Tamas.  If the other calls worked though, that is working fine.  Three things to try that are long shots (in order of 'longness'. 1) Update your version of Numpy. 2) gdal_translate to gtiff and try the code on that image. 3) append ReadAsArray() with .astype(numpy.float32).  Is the image public? I can test it on my machine.  Can you post the stack trace if none of those work?

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot update my version of Numpy, because it is the version that came with ArcGIS and Numpy 1.3 is required for ArcGIS 10.0 (I've tried it in the past).  I did try gdal_translate to GTiff and had the same result.  I also tried with .astype(numpy.float32), and this did not help.  Unfortunately, there is no stack trace to post.  It simply crashes Python and I receive a popup window stating that Python.exe has stopped working.  Please see my update above for more information regarding my investigation.

Comment: The site linked below leads me to believe that this is a numpy 1.3 issue interacting with GDAL.  One option might be to try an OSGEO4W install as this *should* be separate from your Arc install.  Another option might be to give FWTools a try as I know that that is completely separate. Link: http://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/gdal-dev/2010-January/023205.html

Comment: I saw that article in my original investigation of the issue, but I found more articles that explained that it was fixed in the latest dev versions.  That post was with GDAL 1.6.1.  If it was fixed in the dev versions of 1.6.x I would hope it would be fixed at 1.9.1.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6823/discussion-between-jay-laura-and-brian)

Comment: Are you familiar with Python X,Y.  I believe that can optionally include GDAL.  If so, do you know if that would create its own environment that would not interfere with my ArcGIS Python installation?

Comment: Continue step by step. I would for example load in my raster in QGIS and crop it to a small area. Then try to convert it to a numpy array again. If it still fails at least the reason for your error isn't the size of your raster (although i can imagine that numpy/python somewhere has memory restrictions)

Comment: @curlew - Thanks for your input.  I tried the same steps with a different raster that was less than 50 MB with the same result.

Comment: mhh... strange. I've read below that you already tried to convert the file to geoTIFF. Can you upload a small subset or point me to a similar file for testing? Maybe it works for me with my system configuration.

Comment: I do have a small sample image I created using gdal_translate but I'm not sure how to upload it on StackExchange.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As suspected by many commenters, this was an issue with my install.  Apparently, i was not paying close enough attention when installing GDAL and the Python Bindings.

I installed GDAL Core and plugins (dll's) from gisinternals.com, but somehow I didn't think to install the Python Bindings from there as well.  The Python Bindings I installed were from a different site (can't remember which one at this point).

When I reinstalled GDAL and Python Bindings all from gisinternals.com, I was able to successfully ReadAsArray.

Thank you to all who commented and answered and I apologize for my ignorance.

Answer (score 3):

It's possible it's a memory issue. When you use ReadAsArray it brings the data into memory, and while 800mb isn't massive, it's not tiny either. Have you tried reading the array in chunks?

```
data = b.ReadAsArray(x_offset, y_offset, x_size, y_size)
```

You should be able to loop through the array and process it chunk at a time, though depending on the processing you're doing you should probably look to reading in areas with overlap to avoid edge effects.

Comment: I did try using chunks.  I tried `data = b.ReadAsArray(0,0, 500, 500)` with the same result.

Comment: Hmm. I'm assuming you've tried other image formats? Also, was there a specific error message?

Comment: I haven't tried any other formats yet.  there was no error message, just a popup that said "python.exe has stopped working".

Comment: I converted the .img file to a GeoTIFF this morning and tried again.  No luck.

Comment: Is there a way to memory map the file from gdal?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry I'm late to this party, but your basic problem is that 32-bit Python can't store very large rasters in memory.  You can read your large raster into memory in bite-size chunks, but then you're fairly limited in terms of what you can process efficiently without extremely inefficient/frequent read/writes to disk.

What I do instead (which sacrifices some efficiency due to disk read/writes) is to call ([via EXE-wrapping](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/42584/how-to-call-gdal-translate-from-python-code)) the 64-bit gisinternals.com version of whatever gdal method you need. Be careful with using python's subprocess module in a loop (i.e. you may want/need to [call subprocess sequentially](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=90785)) as you may inadvertently generate too many open threads for your windows box and get ominous system warnings.  You sacrifice a little bit in the way to disk read/writes with this gdal approach, but your processing efficiency only drops (i.e. relative to [a lightening fast in-memory computation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23769531/gtiff-mask-with-shapefile-in-python-with-gdal-ogr-etc), if your box/library could support it) by about a factor or 10.