# Use subprocess.call with gdalwarp

Tags: python, gdalwarp

I am now want to use subprocess.call with gdalwarp to clip raster from shapefile
(in qgis 1.8.0)

I use raster→projections→wrap(reproject)to generate command_line below

```
gdalwarp -t_srs "+proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=121 +k=0.9999 +x_0=250000 +y_0=0
+ellps=GRS80 +units=m +no_defs" -dstnodata 0 -q -cutline "C:/Program Files
(x86)/Quantum GIS Wroclaw/test/area.shp"
-dstalpha -of GTiff C:/Program Files
(x86)/Quantum GIS Wroclaw/test/wrapM_0.tif "C:/Program Files
(x86)/Quantum GIS Wroclaw/test/wrap"
```

and following is my code

```
import gdal
from subprocess import call


crs='"+proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=121 +k=0.9999 +x_0=250000 +y_0=0
+ellps=GRS80 +units=m +no_defs"'

mask='"C:/Program Files(x86)/Quantum GIS Wroclaw/test/area.shp"'   
input='C:/Program Files(x86)/Quantum GIS Wroclaw/test/wrapM_0.tif'
output='"C:/Program Files(x86)/Quantum GIS Wroclaw/test/wrap"'

call(gdalwarp, -t_srs crs -dstnodata 0 -q -cutline msak -dstalpha -of GTiff
input output)
```

And Python will give the error below:

```
  File "<input>", line 1
    call(gdalwarp, -t_srs crs -dstnodata 0 -q -cutline msak -dstalpha -of
GTiff input output)
                            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

How to fix the error here??

Comment: Your call function should be like that: call(['gdalwarp', '-t_srs ' + crs, '-dstnodata 0', '-q', '-cutline ' + mask, '-dstalpha', '-of GTIFF', input, output]). I didn't test your code, but is it possible that you missed the double quotes for the Input variable. You use a directory that contains blanks.

Comment: An alternatve to the code above should be: `call('gdalwarp -t_srs ' + crs + ' -dstnodata 0 -q -cutline ' + mask + ' -dstalpha -of GTIFF ' + input + ' ' + output, shell=True)`.

Comment: thanks for your comment!it's worked!but I still have question that I can't find my output shapefile? when I use the plugin it's will give me a file (no extend file name) but after I use call(),it's just flash and nothing left!

Comment: oh it's return 1 in the end of code means it's can't complete the command here but i can run it perfectly via plugin...

Comment: What do you mean with "output shapefile"? Your output file Format is GeoTiff (-of GTiff). You didn't add an extension to your GeoTiff output file in your commandline.

Comment: sorry for that, what I mean is output file!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to specifiy the path to gdalwarp (in the example below I took:  "C:\python32\python.exe", but you have to change it to your intallation path) and change your call function like that:

```
call(['C:\Program Files\GDAL\gdalwarp.exe', '-t_srs ' + crs, '-dstnodata 0', '-q', '-cutline ' + mask, '-dstalpha', '-of GTIFF', input, output]).
```

or:

```
call('C:\Program Files\GDAL\gdalwarp.exe -t_srs ' + crs + ' -dstnodata 0 -q -cutline ' + mask + ' -dstalpha -of GTIFF ' + input + ' ' + output, shell=True)
```

Another possibility is to use the popen function of the subprocess modul. And don't forget to add double quotes for the input variable, since you use a directory that contains blanks.

Have a look at the 2nd answer: [How to call gdal_translate from Python code?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/42584/how-to-call-gdal-translate-from-python-code)

Comment: thanks for help!but I am now have other problem with subprocess.call() even it's can be run by now ~thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I use this method:

import os

command = 'gdalwarp -t_srs crs -dstnodata 0 -q -cutline msak -dstalpha -of GTiff %s %s' % (input, output)

os.system(command)