# Handling multiple-extent-problem to create raster stack in R?

Tags: raster, r, extents, loop, stack

I am storing ~ 30 raster files in a folder and want to create a raster stack. I know that not all of these rasters have completely the same extent. They do have the same resolution and CRS.

Thus I try to set the same extent for all of my rasters in this folder with the following loop in R.

```
#reference raster to get the extent    
a <- raster("F:/SDM/DATA/env_tiff/e_veg_d10.tif")

# where the new rasters will be stored
    outpath <- "F:/SDM/DATA/temp/"
    dir.create(outpath)

    files <- list.files(path="F:/SDM/DATA/env_tiff", pattern=".tif$")   

    # add output directory
    outfiles <- paste0(outpath, files)
    # change extensions
    extension(outfiles) <- 'tif'

    for(i in 1:length(files)) {
      e <- extent(a)
      r <-raster(files[i])
      rc <- crop(r, e)
      rc<- mask(rc, e)
      rw <- writeRaster(rc, outfiles[i], overwrite=TRUE)
      print(outfiles[i])
    }

    #creates a raster stack with all environmental rasters in this file
    env_data <- list.files(path="F:/SDM/DATA/temp", pattern = 'tif$')
    env_data<- stack(env_data)
```

For my loop I get the following Error message:

> Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  :    unable to find an
>   inherited method for function ‘mask’ for signature ‘"RasterLayer",
>   "Extent"’

When I comment the mask part, the loop works, but the extents are still different.

I am also not sure if I choose the right extent, since I don't know the minimum extent. I spent a lot of time searching a way to handle this multiple-extent-problem within my data and found the `crop()` and `mask()` functions.

Comment: There is a funciton "align_rasters" in the gdalUtils package that makes this a bit easier.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can manage multi-extent-problem resampling your data before `mask()` function. This work for aligned and non-aligned pixels (for non-aligned, choose wisely `method` argument). Also, you can use `extend`to align boundaries of your data. I'd made an reproducible example for recreate our problem:

```
library(raster)

a <- raster(xmn=-100, xmx=100, ymn=-90, ymx=90,res=10) 

# for reproducible example
r1 <- raster(xmn=-180, xmx=180, ymn=-90, ymx=90,res=10)
r2 <- raster(xmn=-190, xmx=180, ymn=-80, ymx=10,res=10)
r3 <- raster(xmn=-50, xmx=130, ymn=-80, ymx=90,res=10)

a <- setValues(a, 1:ncell(a))
r1 <- setValues(r1, 1:ncell(r1))
r2 <- setValues(r2, 1:ncell(r2))
r3 <- setValues(r3, 1:ncell(r3))

files <- list()
files[[1]] <- r1
files[[2]] <- r2
files[[3]] <- r3

results <- list()

for(i in 1:length(files)) {
  e <- extent(a)
  r <-files[[i]] # raster(files[i])
  rc <- crop(r, e)
  if(sum(as.matrix(extent(rc))!=as.matrix(e)) == 0){ # edited
    rc <- mask(rc, a) # You can't mask with extent, only with a Raster layer, RStack or RBrick
  }else{
    rc <- extend(rc,a)
    rc<- mask(rc, a)
  }

  # commented for reproducible example      
  results[[i]] <- rc # rw <- writeRaster(rc, outfiles[i], overwrite=TRUE)
  # print(outfiles[i])

}

env_data<- stack(results)
```

The result will depends of the nature of you data, in this case I exaggerated the problem. After this code, we got this:

```
plot(env_data)
```

[image]

---

Edit:

**Test your layers**

```
library(raster)

a <- raster(xmn=-100, xmx=100, ymn=-90, ymx=90,res=10) 

# for reproducible example
r1 <- raster(xmn=-180, xmx=180, ymn=-90, ymx=90,res=10)
r2 <- raster(xmn=-190, xmx=180, ymn=-80, ymx=10,res=10)
r3 <- raster(xmn=-50, xmx=130, ymn=-80, ymx=90,res=10)
# Other posibilities
r4 <- raster(xmn=-200, xmx=-150, ymn=-80, ymx=90,res=10)
r5 <- raster(xmn=-100, xmx=100, ymn=-90, ymx=90,res=5)
r6 <- a

files <- list()
files[[1]] <- r1
files[[2]] <- r2
files[[3]] <- r3
files[[4]] <- r4
files[[5]] <- r5
files[[6]] <- r6

library(testthat)

test <- list()

for(i in 1:length(files)){
  test[[i]] <- capture_warnings(compareRaster(a,files[[i]], res=T, orig=T, stopiffalse=F, showwarning=T))
}

test

[[1]]
[1] "different extent"            "different number or columns"

[[2]]
[1] "different extent"            "different number or columns"
[3] "different number or rows"   

[[3]]
[1] "different extent"            "different number or columns"
[3] "different number or rows"   

[[4]]
[1] "different extent"            "different number or columns"
[3] "different number or rows"   

[[5]]
[1] "different number or columns" "different number or rows"   
[3] "different resolution"       

[[6]]
character(0)
```

Comment: Raster stacks not working with different extents is not entirely true, it depends on what you want to do. You can create a stack with mismatched extents by using the "quick=TRUE" argument.

Comment: Thank you for ansering! The raster cells are aligned but don't match at the borders. What I plan to do is to extract values to points.

Comment: Actually, this code apply to your purposes. I use it in Landsat 8 time series, especially in subsets near to borders.

Comment: I'll try this code and give a feedback soon, Thank you aldo_tapia!

Comment: I tried the code but I am not sure how to integrate it in my code above. I am a newbie in R and coding in general, so could you make some more comments?

Comment: I must confess that I was wrong in diagnosing the problem, but now I have solved it and added an example so that you can understand it better. Try it and tell me how it turns out.

Comment: @ aldo_tapia, your example code works works and I think I understand what it does. Unfortunately, when I use my own data files<- list.files(path="F:/.../temp/", pattern = 'tif$') I get the Error:

Error in .local(.Object, ...) : 
  `C:\Users\...\Documents\aspect.tif' does not exist in the file system,
and is not recognised as a supported dataset name.


Error in .rasterObjectFromFile(x, band = band, objecttype = "RasterLayer",  : 
  Cannot create a RasterLayer object from this file. (file does not exist)

Comment: @parallax add `full.names = T` argument, like `files<- list.files(path="F:/.../temp/", pattern = 'tif$', full.names=T)`. You are listing files inside a folder, if you wanna open it with `raster::raster()` you have two options: 1) same working directory and path. 2) raster name with path, could be absolute or relative path (I always use this option).

Comment: oh, yes of course! But now I get teh following Error after the Loop (before building the raster stack. Error in compareRaster(x, mask) : different extent. I also have two other questions. What exactly does this line do: if(sum(as.matrix(extent(rc))!=as.matrix(e)) == 4)? It compares the sum ob the current raster in the if statement and the reference raster a, if the pixels are unequal it starts resampling, otherwhise it get's maskes by a. Will I lose information by resampling? Thank you aldo_tapia!

Comment: a) The code `if(sum(as.matrix(extent(rc))!=as.matrix(e)) == 4)` tests extreme coordinates of both rasters (_xmin_, _xmax_, _ymin_, _ymax_). If a pair of coordinates is equal, result is TRUE (or 1), so if four pairs of coordinates are TRUE, the sum of them it's equal to 4. If this happend, no resample is needed.
b) If pixels are aligned, `resample` only will help you to align extents, no value will be touched... But if pixels aren't aligned, there'll be another process. I changed `resample` with `extend` to prevent _bilinear_ _interpolation_ or _ngb_.

Comment: About `Error in compareRaster(x, mask) : different extent.`... Are you working with same CRS for all data? Maybe that's the key of your problem.

Comment: yes they should have the same crs. I'm working with wgs 84 utm 33n.

Comment: I just add new code lines. It are related to evaluate if your raster layer are in the extend that you want.

Comment: Thank you! I adjusted it to my files, and got "flase" for every raster. So I assume that they are of same extent. But why do I get the `Error in compareRaster(x, mask) : different extent` when trying to mask the rasters?

Comment: Check the answer now. Test all variation along your data. If this doesn't solve your problem, I can't do more without view your data.

Comment: Also, re-run the above code. I edit a number (I used today to fix the same problem on my own data). Good luck!

Comment: Well, this is funny now. There are multiple mismatches. Running the code above brings my laptop to his limit: `Reached total allocation of 3999Mb: see help(memory.size)`. Maybe writing the processed rasters directly to the disc will prevent this problem?

Comment: Exactly. Instead `results[[i]] <- rc`, use `writeRaster(rc, paste("rastername",i,".tif",sep=""))` or something like that.... Also add `removeTmpFiles(time)` at the end of the loop, is the time in hours to search and delete raster temp files. Yesterday I used `removeTmpFiles(0.1)` in a loop for 600 Landsat scenes with no problem. Near 200GB of data was generated (time series of 4 different path/row processing NDVI with cloud/cloud shadow mask).

Comment: puhh, this was a hard piece of work for a beginner! But now it works, I can create the raster stack, without the message about different extents. Your testing script returns 0 for all rasters, and a visual review in QGIS doesn't show a mismatch! Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome. Happy to know that works for you

Answer (score 0):

Crop can write straight to file; I don't think the mask step is necessary? you should make sure your extent aligns with pixel edges though - see here [Improving Clip Raster workflow in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/199258/improving-clip-raster-workflow-in-qgis/214076#214076)