# Unable to extract pixel values from some of the Sentinel 2A images

Tags: geotiff-tiff, sentinel-2, extract

I have an obstacle which I thus far wasn't able to overcome. I have gigabytes of Sentinel 2 imagery from which I need to extract pixel images. Firstly, I have converted the images to .tif files. After that, in some cases, the extract function works as I expect it to:

```
        image=raster("E:/S2A_USER_MSI_L2A_TL_SGS__20160317T153554_ 
        A003837_T33TWJ_B8A_20m.tif")
        typeof(image)

    [1] "S4

        str(image)

            Formal class 'RasterLayer' [package "raster"] with 12 slots
              ..@ file    :Formal class '.RasterFile' [package "raster"] with 13 slots
              .. .. ..@ name        : chr "E:\\0103_2404\\S2A_USER_PRD_MSIL2A_PDMC_20160309T094150_R136_V20160308T093139_20160308T093139.SAFE\\GRANULE\\S2"|
        __truncated__
              .. .. ..@ datanotation: chr "INT2U"
              .. .. ..@ byteorder   : chr "little"
              .. .. ..@ nodatavalue : num -Inf
              .. .. ..@ NAchanged   : logi FALSE
              .. .. ..@ nbands      : int 1
              .. .. ..@ bandorder   : chr "BIL"
              .. .. ..@ offset      : int 0
              .. .. ..@ toptobottom : logi TRUE
              .. .. ..@ blockrows   : int 1
              .. .. ..@ blockcols   : int 5490
              .. .. ..@ driver      : chr "gdal"
              .. .. ..@ open        : logi FALSE
              ..@ data    :Formal class '.SingleLayerData' [package "raster"] with 13 slots
              .. .. ..@ values    : logi(0) 
              .. .. ..@ offset    : num 0
              .. .. ..@ gain      : num 1
              .. .. ..@ inmemory  : logi FALSE
              .. .. ..@ fromdisk  : logi TRUE
              .. .. ..@ isfactor  : logi FALSE
              .. .. ..@ attributes: list()
              .. .. ..@ haveminmax: logi TRUE
              .. .. ..@ min       : num 0
              .. .. ..@ max       : num 65535
              .. .. ..@ band      : int 1
              .. .. ..@ unit      : chr ""
              .. .. ..@ names     : chr "S2A_USER_MSI_L2A_TL_SGS__20160317T153554_A003837_T33TWJ_B8A_20m"
              ..@ legend  :Formal class '.RasterLegend' [package "raster"] with 5 slots
              .. .. ..@ type      : chr(0) 
              .. .. ..@ values    : logi(0) 
              .. .. ..@ color     : logi(0) 
              .. .. ..@ names     : logi(0) 
              .. .. ..@ colortable: logi(0) 
              ..@ title   : chr(0) 
              ..@ extent  :Formal class 'Extent' [package "raster"] with 4 slots
              .. .. ..@ xmin: num 5e+05
              .. .. ..@ xmax: num 609780
              .. .. ..@ ymin: num 4790220
              .. .. ..@ ymax: num 4900020
              ..@ rotated : logi FALSE
              ..@ rotation:Formal class '.Rotation' [package "raster"] with 2 slots
              .. .. ..@ geotrans: num(0) 
              .. .. ..@ transfun:function ()  
              ..@ ncols   : int 5490
              ..@ nrows   : int 5490
              ..@ crs     :Formal class 'CRS' [package "sp"] with 1 slot
              .. .. ..@ projargs: chr "+proj=utm +zone=33 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0"
              ..@ history : list()
              ..@ z       : list()

        pixel_values=(na.omit(extract(image,azo_plohe, cellnumbers=TRUE, 
        weights=TRUE, df=TRUE)))


     ID   CELL pxl_value  Weight
1   320 5625881 0   0.034532374
2   320 5625882 0   0.082014388
3   320 5625883 0   0.027338129
4   320 5631371 0   0.135251799
5   320 5631372 0   0.143884892
6   320 5631373 0   0.122302158
7   320 5636861 0   0.125179856
8   320 5636862 0   0.143884892
9   320 5636863 0   0.110791367
```

In this case my first 9 pixels are on the areas where it is all black so the values are zero, but the function works. However, in some other cases when I use this same function on another image:

```
image=raster("E:/SS2A_USER_MSI_L2A_TL_SGS__ 20160308T165710_A003708_T34TCN_B12_20.
typeof(image)

  [1] "S4

            str(image)

Formal class 'RasterLayer' [package "raster"] with 12 slots
  ..@ file    :Formal class '.RasterFile' [package "raster"] with 13 slots
  .. .. ..@ name        : chr "E:\\0103_2404\\S2A_USER_PRD_MSIL2A_PDMC_20160309T094150_R136_V20160308T093139_20160308T093139.SAFE\\GRANULE\\S2"| __truncated__
  .. .. ..@ datanotation: chr "INT2U"
  .. .. ..@ byteorder   : chr "little"
  .. .. ..@ nodatavalue : num -Inf
  .. .. ..@ NAchanged   : logi FALSE
  .. .. ..@ nbands      : int 1
  .. .. ..@ bandorder   : chr "BIL"
  .. .. ..@ offset      : int 0
  .. .. ..@ toptobottom : logi TRUE
  .. .. ..@ blockrows   : int 1
  .. .. ..@ blockcols   : int 5490
  .. .. ..@ driver      : chr "gdal"
  .. .. ..@ open        : logi FALSE
  ..@ data    :Formal class '.SingleLayerData' [package "raster"] with 13 slots
  .. .. ..@ values    : logi(0) 
  .. .. ..@ offset    : num 0
  .. .. ..@ gain      : num 1
  .. .. ..@ inmemory  : logi FALSE
  .. .. ..@ fromdisk  : logi TRUE
  .. .. ..@ isfactor  : logi FALSE
  .. .. ..@ attributes: list()
  .. .. ..@ haveminmax: logi TRUE
  .. .. ..@ min       : num 0
  .. .. ..@ max       : num 65535
  .. .. ..@ band      : int 1
  .. .. ..@ unit      : chr ""
  .. .. ..@ names     : chr "S2A_USER_MSI_L2A_TL_SGS__20160308T165710_A003708_T34TCN_B12_20m"
  ..@ legend  :Formal class '.RasterLegend' [package "raster"] with 5 slots
  .. .. ..@ type      : chr(0) 
  .. .. ..@ values    : logi(0) 
  .. .. ..@ color     : logi(0) 
  .. .. ..@ names     : logi(0) 
  .. .. ..@ colortable: logi(0) 
  ..@ title   : chr(0) 
  ..@ extent  :Formal class 'Extent' [package "raster"] with 4 slots
  .. .. ..@ xmin: num 3e+05
  .. .. ..@ xmax: num 409800
  .. .. ..@ ymin: num 4690200
  .. .. ..@ ymax: num 4800000
  ..@ rotated : logi FALSE
  ..@ rotation:Formal class '.Rotation' [package "raster"] with 2 slots
  .. .. ..@ geotrans: num(0) 
  .. .. ..@ transfun:function ()  
  ..@ ncols   : int 5490
  ..@ nrows   : int 5490
  ..@ crs     :Formal class 'CRS' [package "sp"] with 1 slot
  .. .. ..@ projargs: chr "+proj=utm +zone=34 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0"
  ..@ history : list()
  ..@ z       : list()

           pixel_values=(na.omit(extract(image,azo_plohe, cellnumbers=TRUE, 
            weights=TRUE, df=TRUE)))

Error in names(x) <- value : 'names' attribute [4] must be the same length as the vector [0]
```

I do not understand why i can not execute extract function on this 2 seemengly same .tif files. So far i wasn't able to see any pattern why some images pixels are normally extracted and why some aren't. I know that if i remove the

```
df=TRUE
```

I do not get the error. But the thing is that i need this part for the rest of my code which can be found on this link ([How to get feature values from multiple polygons of shapefile while using extract function on raster](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/260978/how-to-get-feature-values-from-multiple-polygons-of-shapefile-while-using-extrac?noredirect=1#comment413382_260978)). IF I remove the "df=TRUE" I get another error

```
Error in .doXYFromCell(object@ncols, object@nrows, e@xmin, e@xmax, e@ymin,  : 
Not compatible with requested type: [type=NULL; target=double].
```

Sidenote, some images return null values because they are not in my area of interest so the extract works OK on SOME of them. But, I have noticed that images that give error when trying to extract are all outside of my area of interes. This is my newest clue regarding the problem of extraction.

Comment: Seems to be a problem with a long path name... But I'm not sure... Why convert S-2A images to tiff ? `rgdal` supports jpg-2000 (if you update gdal)

Comment: Hmmm, the paths are always long and should always be the same beacuse of the structure of folders when downloading Sentinel imagery (https://earth.esa.int/web/sentinel/user-guides/sentinel-2-msi/data-formats ) . If this were the problem then i shouldnt be able to extract pixels from any of the images right?  I converted to tif because I couldn't coarse R  into reading jp2 rasters with "raster(x)" function, even though i have several gdal jp2 drivers.

Comment: Yes, I know S-2*.SAFE folder structure... But for many softwares is an issue (also, working in windows). Only in SNAP everything works fine. I'm an OS X user and [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/260487/80215) helped me to set-up gdal correctly in R to open S-2 images (S-2A and S-2B)

Comment: @davorkorman, I was also converting to GeoTIFF to work with S2 data in R. After uploading rgdal, I am able to use the jp2 format in R. Which version are you using? It may save you a step in your methodology. Anyways, did you try to save your tiff S2 files in a new path, out of the .SAFE structure? I usually do that and when extracting pixel values I do not face any problem.

Comment: I am using 2.2.1. on Windows 10. Then it is possible that in future I might save a step with the conversion. I have found out that if i loose the "df=TRUE" in my code, I do not get the error "Error in names(x) <- value : 'names' attribute [4] must be the same length as the vector [0]"., but i get this error "Error in .doXYFromCell(object@ncols, object@nrows, e@xmin, e@xmax, e@ymin, : Not compatible with requested type: [type=NULL; target=double].". This error is a part of a bigger code I posted as another question. If you are interested in further helping I will post it bellow this coment.

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/260978/how-to-get-feature-values-from-multiple-polygons-of-shapefile-while-using-extrac?noredirect=1#comment413382_260978