# Raster stack different extent for same site?

Tags: raster, r, extents, map-matching, rasterstack

I have rasters for the same area (same polygon) but I am not sure why they have different extent. I had an supervised classified layer of the initial DEM and secondary variables that do not match the extent of the source. I georeferenced one of the layers so the different extent makes sense but now I need to match the extent of 60+ rasters to the original raster. I saw online posts for Alignraster in R and read through multiple forums with their script in R but their issue is a bit different than mine since my layers are all the same area, same site, shape etc. but are slightly offset.

Theoretically, what approach would you recommend to batch process or loop through the stack?

Comment: You could compute the smallest extent, create a raster (with the same resolution and crs as your rasters) from that extent, then resample all your rasters based on that. Does https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/217082/handling-multiple-extent-problem-to-create-raster-stack-in-r help?

Comment: There is also an answer on stackoverflow that might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20733555/how-to-create-a-raster-brick-with-rasters-of-different-extents