# GDAL command lines on windows

Tags: gdal, windows, python-2.7

I am trying to get started with GDAL on a windows machine using Python2.7.
I have tried commands such as:

`gdalinfo RasterFileName.TIF and gdal_translate.py -projwin ulx uly lrx lry -of GTiff input.TIF output.TIF`

and they run without producing any results. What am I missing that makes these not to work.

For example, I am doing the gdal_translate as follows:

```
    import os
    infile = path+'InFileName.TIF'
    outfile = path+'OUTFileName.TIF'
    string ='gdal_translate -projwin %.0f %.0f %.0f %.0f -of GTiff %s %s' %(ulx,uly,lrx,lry,infile,outfile)
    os.system(string)
```

Many thanks

Comment: Do these run without wrapping them in a python script?  What is the output of `gdalinfo <some raster>` via the command line?

Comment: Do you want to use GDAL in Python or just in the command line? For GDAL in Python try `import gdal
gdal.VersionInfo()` in Python. For GDAL in the command line try `gdalinfo --version` in the command line. What are you getting?

Comment: I am getting   'gdal.VersionInfo' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Comment: Do you want to use it in Python? If so, you have to `import gdal` and then try `gdal.VersionInfo()` with parentheses.

Comment: Yes I want to use Python. The command 'gdal.Version()' gives me '1100100'. So in python how would I use 'gdal_translate'.

Comment: You might find this question helpful: [How to apply “Band” settings using gdal Python bindings?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/75533/how-to-apply-band-settings-using-gdal-python-bindings)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Windows, you have to load the GDAL environment variable to make the command-line utilities to work. With MS4W, for example, you have to run setenv.bat. This set some GDAL environment variables. I suspect your script doesn't have those variable set. You could probably run it before your script.