# Georeferencing raster using GDAL and Python?

Tags: python, raster, gdal, coordinate-system, gdalwarp

I want to georeference a raster using `python` and `GDAL`. My current approach is to call `gdal_translate` and `gdalwarp` using `os.system` and an ugly list of ground control points. I'd really like a way to do this natively within `python`.

This is the current process I am using:

```
import os

os.system('gdal_translate -of GTiff -gcp 1251.92 414.538 -7.9164e+06 5.21094e+06 -gcp 865.827 107.699 -7.91651e+06 5.21104e+06  "inraster.tif" "outraster1.tif"')
os.system('gdalwarp -r bilinear -tps -co COMPRESS=NONE "outraster2.tif" "outraster3.tif"')
```

There is a previous [question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/42584/how-to-call-gdal-translate-from-python-code) and [answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/42621/803) from 2012 which states that `gdal_translate` can be accessed after importing `gdal`. I'm not sure if is obsolete, or whether it is wrong but when I run `from osgeo import gdal` I do not see `gdal.gdal_translate` as an option.

I don't know if it exists but I would love if I could translate and reproject rasters in a pythonic way. For example:

```
# translate
gcp_points = [(1251.92, 414.538), (-7.9164e+06, 5.21094e+06)]
gdal.gdal_translate(in_raster, gcp_points, out_raster1)

# warp
gdal.gdalwarp(out_raster1, out_raster2, 'bilinear', args*)
```

Is such an approach possible?

Comment: gdal_translate and gdalwarp and other [gdal utilities](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_utilities.html) are not python packages/modules, they are standalone executables. You can use os.system or (preferably) subprocess.Popen to call them.

Comment: @Luke so is there no way of interacting with these gdal utilities? I'd be happy to explore how to write a python wrapper for these if one does not exist.

Comment: You can use the gdal python API to do nearly everything the gdal_translate and gdalwarp utilities can, it's just a bit more complicated. Check out gdal.AutoCreateWarpedVRT and gdal Driver.CreateCopy.

Answer (score 20):

Here is an example that does roughly what you ask for. The main parameters are the `geotransform` array that gdal uses to describe a raster location (position, pixel scale, and skew) and the `epsg` code of the projection. With that, the following code should properly georeference the raster and specify its projection.

I did not test this much, but it seemed to work for me. You would have to make sure the coordinates I put in are correct and probably change the projection and the pixel scale/size. Hope it helps.

```
from osgeo import gdal, osr

src_filename ='/path/to/source.tif'
dst_filename = '/path/to/destination.tif'

# Opens source dataset
src_ds = gdal.Open(src_filename)
format = "GTiff"
driver = gdal.GetDriverByName(format)

# Open destination dataset
dst_ds = driver.CreateCopy(dst_filename, src_ds, 0)

# Specify raster location through geotransform array
# (uperleftx, scalex, skewx, uperlefty, skewy, scaley)
# Scale = size of one pixel in units of raster projection
# this example below assumes 100x100
gt = [-7916400, 100, 0, 5210940, 0, -100]

# Set location
dst_ds.SetGeoTransform(gt)

# Get raster projection
epsg = 3857
srs = osr.SpatialReference()
srs.ImportFromEPSG(epsg)
dest_wkt = srs.ExportToWkt()

# Set projection
dst_ds.SetProjection(dest_wkt)

# Close files
dst_ds = None
src_ds = None
```

Comment: It is right but if you want to be more accurate, in case of rotation, you have to use the Affine Transformation and calculate the right parameters with Affine package ([download from here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/affine/2.0.0.post1)).
Usage:
'Affine.scale(PARAMETER)*Affine.rotation(ANGLE)'.
PARAMETER are from the pixel ratio of the two image, you can use 'gdalinfo' or PIL to know the pixel size, ANGLE is the angle.

Comment: In addition, here is how I found "gt" for the solution: reference = r'D:\....tif'

src = gdal.Open(reference)
ulx, xres, xskew, uly, yskew, yres  = src.GetGeoTransform(). And simply add gt = [ulx, xres, xskew, uly, yskew, yres ]

Comment: How do I do this with multiple GCP points? 2D array maintaining `[(uperleftx, scalex, skewx, uperlefty, skewy, scaley),(...)]`?