# Creating (x,y) coordinates in .nc from .grib2

Tags: python, pyproj, grib-2, rioxarray

I have to use a .nc file as input in a model and such model requires *projection_x_coordinate* and *projection_y_coordinate* as variables but I don't have them. Is it possible to create them using pyproj, for instance? (file available [here](https://github.com/vic1309/gribfile)). My projparams are:

> ```
> {'a': 6371229,
>  'b': 6371229,
>  'proj': 'stere',
>  'lat_ts': 60.0,
>  'lat_0': 90.0,
>  'lon_0': 264.0}
> ```

My first idea was to use the information of the number of points (Nx in the file), the horizontal resolution (Dx) and the first points (*e.g.* latitudeOfFirstGridPointInDegrees) to create the desired variables but I don't know if it is the right thing to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be interested in [rioxarray](https://github.com/corteva/rioxarray).

EDIT: with `rioxarray>=0.0.31` and `rasterio>=1.1.5` you should only need to do:

```
import rioxarray
rds = rioxarray.open_rasterio("CMC_caps_HGT_ISBL_0050_ps3km_2018090900_P005.grib2")
rds.to_netcdf("CMC_caps_HGT_ISBL_0050_ps3km_2018090900_P005_coord.nc")
```

Otherwise:

Due to https://github.com/mapbox/rasterio/issues/1248, you cannot use `rioxarray.open_rasterio` to generate CRS/coordinate info.

So, you will have to do it manually:

```py
from rioxarray.rioxarray import affine_to_coords
import rasterio

with rasterio.Env(), rasterio.open("CMC_caps_HGT_ISBL_0050_ps3km_2018090900_P005.grib2") as rrr:
    riocrs = rrr.crs
    coords = affine_to_coords(rrr.transform, rrr.width, rrr.height)
```

Then, you can use `rioxarray` to read in the data, add attrs, and write to netcdf:

```py
from pyproj.crs import CRS
import rioxarray

rds = rioxarray.open_rasterio("CMC_caps_HGT_ISBL_0050_ps3km_2018090900_P005.grib2", parse_coordinates=False)
rds = rds.assign_coords(coords)
rds.rio.write_crs(riocrs, inplace=True)
rds.spatial_ref.attrs.update(CRS.from_user_input(riocrs).to_cf())
rds.x.attrs["long_name"] = "x coordinate of projection"
rds.x.attrs["standard_name"] = "projection_x_coordinate"
rds.y.attrs["long_name"] = "y coordinate of projection"
rds.y.attrs["standard_name"] = "projection_y_coordinate"
rds.to_netcdf("CMC_caps_HGT_ISBL_0050_ps3km_2018090900_P005_coord.nc")
```

Comment: it worked like a dream! Thank you, @snowman2

Comment: I am glad to hear that it worked 