# Projecting gtiff data using GDAL and Python?

Tags: python, coordinate-system, gdal, geotiff-tiff, georeferencing

I have a tile data and I would like to transform the data to a gtiff data with georeference information via gdal and python.

The tile is the quadtree tile with quad key `1321222320321122`. The left upper point of this tile is `Point(114.14794921875 22.33991442556202)`(the right lower point of this tile is `Point(114.1534423828125,22.334833457530486)` in case of use). The original tile file is a 256*256 png file.

I refered the code from [Georeferencing raster using GDAL and Python?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/116672)

Here is my code:

```
src_ds = gdal.Open(src_path)
driver = gdal.GetDriverByName('GTiff')

dst_ds = driver.CreateCopy(dst_path,src_ds,0)
# Set projection
gt = [114.14794921875,256,0,22.33991442556202,0,-256]

dst_ds.SetGeoTransform(gt)

srs = osr.SpatialReference()
srs.ImportFromEPSG(4326)
dest_wkt = srs.ExportToWkt()

dst_ds.SetProjection(dest_wkt)

dst_ds = None
src_ds = None
```

Then I directly put the generated gtiff data to QGIS, but the figure is not in a proper location (neither it locates in the same place as the origin figure.) The layer extent is (114.1479492187500000,-65513.6600855744400178 : 65650.1479492187500000,22.3399144255620214). So there must something wrong with the transform process, and I am wondering what is the right transform parameter in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The scale parameters are the size of a pixel in the X and Y directions. You've put "256". That's the *number* of pixels.

To work out the correct value, divide the width of your image in coordinates (114.1534423828125 - 114.14794921875) by the number of pixels (256), and the same for the height.

This is all explained in the documentation.