# Georeference one image using GCPs from another image

Tags: python, gdal, opencv

I have two GeoTIFFs, one of which is misaligned spatially. I used opencv to do some quick feature matching between the two to automatically identify GCPs existing in both images. How would I go about warping the misaligned image such that it aligns with source/reference layer? I have the geotransforms for each image and the GCPs in both image and geospace.

[image]

Comment: You have a list of pixel coordinates from your image and the real-world coordinates in some CRS?  If so, look here:  https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/116672/georeferencing-raster-using-gdal-and-python

Comment: Whats funny is I did that exact thing earlier and the result wasn't as expected. Made a small tweak in the GCPs and it worked!