Associating corresponding images with layer containing tiles
I have several layers of georeferenced tiles that I have gathered in a single layer and I am trying to assign the coordinates of the corresponding images to each tile.

A first step allowed me to create an attribute containing the paths of each image and the 2nd step allowed me to get the vertices of each image (the number of lines is multiplied by 4 because there are 4 vertices per image.


the 3rd step (from @GBG) allowed me to understand how to use the Gdal_translate command. I managed to georeference an image with the command:
gdal_translate -of GTiff -gcp 0 0 989692.497 6278595.709 -gcp 2795 0 994917.429 6279290.609 -gcp 2795 2998 995749.236 6273926.478 -gcp 0 2998 990620.804 6272998.840 "D:/__SIG__/nouvel_essai/2003_mission_768/a03_m768_p503.jpg" "D:/__SIG__/nouvel_essai/2003_mission_768/a03_m768_p503.tif"


now:
to automate the calculation on hundreds of images, I must now retrieve in a text file, the initial vertices of each slab (for the moment I know how to retrieve this information for an image via the property window (Upper Left / Lower Left / Upper Right / Lower Right)

How can I retrieve the values ​​of the initial vertices of each image from the paths of each image?
Even a text file would be suitable for output.

Your images look like they overlap so you can try something like OpenDroneMap to mosaic them together.  Other options (if you know which side of the polygon is the top of the image) would be to code the georeferencing.   Look here https://kokoalberti.com/articles/georeferencing-and-digitizing-old-maps-with-gdal/ and here for starters  https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/116672/georeferencing-raster-using-gdal-and-python

@GBG thank you, the article is very interesting but I don't see how to apply it to my case

The articles apply in this case because they show you how to take the coordinate values of your polygon corners (not the OID values of the verticies  that you have shown above) and correlate those values with your image coordinate corners to automate the georeferencing process.

Do you want to do this with a tool like the Plug-in georeferencing tool or with code?  You could create a .jgw (world file) for each image with code. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_file

@GBG you are certainly right, but I can't apply the method.
in my case, I have the slab layer, a column points the paths of each image (knowing that there are several image directories and several images per directory). I extracted the vertices of the slabs and calculated the x, y points of each vertex.
This vertex layer the x, y of the vertices of each image as well as the path of the images.

@ Cary H I have several dozen directories containing dozens of images (aerial photos) and a georeferenced slab layer.
I simply want to associate the images with the slabs.
I managed to extract the vertices of each corner of each image (4 pairs of x, y coordinates for each image).
This vertex layer also includes the path of the images.
I know how to use the georeferencing tool but in this case I am looking for a method that allows me to automate the georeferencing of images.

I think you have missed the information in the Kokalberti.com article.  If you know your image size, say you have an image of 500 pixels wide and 400 pixels tall, and you know the real-world coordinate values at those corners, you can use Python to automate the georeferencing.  Read your data columns with file names and coordinate values and produce a gdal command to handle the georeferencing.
You can execute those commands in a Python window in QGIS.
As I mentioned in my comments, this all depends on whether you know which of your 4 coordinate corner points correspond to which corners of the images.  Once you know that you build the gdal command.  If you get this wrong the image will be flipped, inverted, or rotated and likely stretched in the wrong direction.
Here is a basic example of a gdal command for georeferencing.   I show long and lat values but you can substitute your y and x values as shown in your table.
gdal_translate -gcp imageX imageY long lat -of GTiff original.jpg map-with-gcps.tif

The images coordinate origin is in the upper left corner of the image (0,0) so in the example below I go top left, top right, bottom left bottom right.
gdal_translate -gcp 0 0 long1 lat1 \
-gcp 500 0 long2 lat2\
-gcp 0 400 long3 lat3\
-gcp 500 400 long4 lat4 -of GTiff original.jpg georeferenced.tif

All of this depends on a modicum of Python skills.  For help on reading your data column with Python, or running command line arguments with Python you should post new and specific questions to GIS SE.
Here are some other helpful links to get you going in the right direction.
Reading image exif with PIL to get image sizes.
Executing command line arguments in Python.
Read attribute tables with QGIS and Python.

thanks.
i think i understood.
i managed to georeference an image with the command:
gdal_translate -of GTiff -gcp 0 0 989692.497 6278595.709 -gcp 2795 0 994917.429 6279290.609 -gcp 2795 2998 995749.236 6273926.478 -gcp 0 2998 990620.804 6272998.840 "D:/SIG/nouvel_essai/2003_mission_768/a03_m768_p503.jpg" "D:/SIG/nouvel_essai/2003_mission_768/a03_m768_p503.tif"
