# Convert netcdf4 to ASCII using Python and gdal: No output

Tags: python, gdal, netcdf, raster-conversion, esri-ascii-raster

I want to convert a netCDF4 dataset (including grouped datasets) to Arc/Info ASCII Grids, using Python's `gdal` package. I tried to orientate at [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/42584/how-to-call-gdal-translate-from-python-code) question, the only thing I added is a loop over the subdatasets. Now, however, something went wrong and the script doesn't produce any output.

Can anyone help? Here's my code:

```
#Open existing dataset
src_ds_list = glob("..\\*.nc")

for path in src_ds_list:
    src_ds = gdal.Open(path)
    subdata = src_ds.GetSubDatasets()

    for s in range(len(subdata)):
        sds = gdal.Open(subdata[s][0])

        dst_path = '..\\' + subdata[s][0] + 'arbitrary' + '.asc'

        # Open output format driver, see gdal_translate --formats for list
        oformat = "AAIGrid"
        driver = gdal.GetDriverByName(oformat)
        # Output to new format
        dst_ds = driver.CreateCopy(dst_path, sds, 0)
        dst_ds = None
        sds= None
    src_ds = None
```

Comment: Does it work when not looping?

Comment: No, because it cannot write multiple datasets into one ASCII Grid - or what do you mean by this comment?

Comment: No I meant unrolling the loop. Does it work if you just try to write the first subdata set?

Comment: Unfortunately not...does this give any hint?

Comment: Go step by step then, maybe interactively in a Python shell. Does sds actually contain the data you expect. Does getting the driver succeed? Etc

Answer (score 1):

A one-liner would be (if you have gdal installed):

```
gdal_translate -of aaigrid netcdf:in.nc:Band1 out.txt
```

**EDIT For doing in python**

Use subprocess as:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call('gdal_translate -of aaigrid netcdf:in.nc:Band1 out.txt')
```

You can then use the resultant file as normal and continue along with the script in python.

Comment: Cool idea, unfortunately not in Python! :/

Comment: I have edited my answer to reflect what you want, hope that helps.