# Use GDAL Python API to generate mbtiles

Tags: python, gdal, mbtiles

I want to create mbtiles with the GDAL Python API. How can I integrate format specific options like `"TILE_FORMAT = 'jpeg', QUALITY='90'"` for mbtiles?

```
from osgeo import gdal

path = r'C:\Users\go\my.vrt'
pathout = r'C:\Users\go\my.mbtiles'
src_ds = gdal.Open(path)
ds = gdal.Translate(pathout , src_ds, format = 'mbtiles')
ds = No
```

Comment: You can pass them as parameter(s). See https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/352643/gdal-translate-in-python-where-do-i-find-how-to-convert-the-command-line-argum/352647#352647 for some example.

Comment: that's do not work in my test. Because thats mbtiles specific options and not gdal.translate options that i want to add.
i tested it with: `ds = gdal.Translate(pathout , src_ds, format = 'mbtiles', TILE_FORMAT = 'jpeg', QUALITY='90')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those are [Creation Options](https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/mbtiles.html#creation-options). You can pass Creation Options to `gdal.Translate` using the `creationOptions` parameter. The names are the same as for the `gdal.TranslateOptions` function: https://gdal.org/python/osgeo.gdal-module.html#TranslateOptions

They are to be `key=value` pairs as strings in a list.

For your example:

```
creation_options = ["TILE_FORMAT=JPEG", "QUALITY=90"]

ds = gdal.Translate(
    pathout, src_ds, 
    format='mbtiles', creationOptions=creation_options
)
```

Comment: Thats it, but one little misstake: creationOptions = creation_options.
Thanks!

Comment: Thaanks, fixed!