# Converting Orthomosaic TIF Image to COG (Cloud-Optimized Geo-TIFF)

Tags: python, orthophoto, cloud-optimized-geotiff, agisoft-photoscan

I have successfully generated an orthomosaic TIF image from a road survey consisting of approximately 1200 images. These images are all located along a single line, reflecting the nature of a road survey. To generate the orthomosaic, I used the Agisoft engine, which has performed well up to this point.

However, when I attempt to convert this generated orthomosaic TIF image into a COG using the `rio cogeo create input.tif output.tif` command, I encounter some unknown issues that prevent the conversion from completing successfully.

How do I troubleshoot and resolve this issue?

Does anyone have experience with similar conversions or can recommend alternative methods to achieve the desired COG output?

Comment: Is "some unknown issues" really all that you know about the problem?

Comment: I have also attempted this on multiple systems with high specifications, but the same issue persists. I successfully converted the 25 GB orthomosaic TIF but encountered an issue with the 12 GB orthomosaic TIF, generated from a road survey. The log indicates that the orthomosaic TIF is created but not written when attempting to convert it into COG.

Comment: Show the logs then.

Answer (score 1):

A first test might be to confirm whether rio is working correctly.  You could do the conversion with GDAL as I see there is a [COG raster driver](https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/cog.html#raster-cog) for GDAL.

I think this command would work but I have not tried a COG conversion myself.

```
gdal_translate -of COG <input filename> <output filename>
```

If you have ArcGIS or QGIS installed you would have access to the GDAL Python bindings and I see [there is a Python solution posted here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/352643/gdal-translate-in-python-where-do-i-find-how-to-convert-the-command-line-argum).

Comment: I preferred using GDAL for COG conversion initially but encountered installation issues. Therefore, I opted for "rio cogeo create" as an alternative solution.

Comment: There is also cogger https://github.com/airbusgeo/cogger that is made for converting generic tiffs into cogs.